# Animate with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate the "margin-left" via "animate()" jQuery, where the value of "margin-left" is saved in a variable dynamically and **not hard-coded** as in

```
$('.animate-box').animate({'margin-left': '+=60'}) // value is not hard-coded like this
```

but rather like this so that the value can be dynamically changed.

```
$('.animate-box').animate({'margin-left': +=margin}// like this
```

But I could not get it animated for some reason. [Fiddle to the Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/littleanimboy/2c1b3v2z/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. You left out a period in your selector. It should be `var margin = $('.top-box').width();`
2. Second you need to enclose the `+=` in quotes and concatenate it with the value. `'margin-left': '+=' + margin`

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2c1b3v2z/1/)**